# Is there any traditional ways to bypass Gmail two-factor-authentication (2FA)? Please explain if it is possible

Tags: multi-factor

I'm currently using 4 or 5 Gmail and I'm using 2FA in all of my Gmail. So I want to know is it possible to bypass Gmail 2FA system? If it is possible then what it is? And I also use strong password which is nearly unhackable according to kaspersky.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be an exhaustive list, but some ways come to mind:

- Infect your phone and PC with malware in order to intercept both the password and the 2FA code.
- Infect your PC or public computer with malware and hijack a logged-in browser session.
- Phish you to gain access to your account and add an application password or disable 2FA.
- Phish customer support at Google to temporarily disable 2FA. (I lost my phone and really need access to my account, I can tell you my mother's maiden name and my place of birth and everything!)
- Phish or keylog temporary access codes which you set up in case of not having your 2FA device available.
- If you're using SMS instead of the Authenticator app, trick your mobile carrier into switching your phone number to a phone they control.
- Gain access to another email account you've set up as a recovery account, to reset your login information.
- Physically steal your 2FA device.